# Problems with android studio and quasar

Tags: java, android, vue.js, android-studio, quasar

I work with quasar.
I try initiating the project with these commands:

```
quasar build -m capacitor -T android
quasar dev -m capacitor -T android
```

but when I insert the first command [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKWjU.png) appears

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
> Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7 [in thread "Daemon worker"]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I just run additional " --ide ", like:

`quasar build -m capacitor -T android --ide`

They are open Android Studio and then you can test it or build it for Play Market :)